# What is 'optical phaseshift'?

Tags: optics, waves, laser, interferometry, photonics

In interferometry, it is said that lasers can be used to measure the 'optical phaseshift' of something. I am familiar with the concept of [*phase* in the context of waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)), but I don't understand exactly what is meant by 'optical phaseshift'. What is 'optical phaseshift'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am familiar with the concept of phase in the context of waves,

Light waves are waves. The optical phase shift is the phase shift of a light wave.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So 'optical phaseshift' is the *shift/change of the phase of the light wave that interacts with the 'something' in question*?

Comment: In the context of an interferometer, usually it will measure the difference in phase shift between two paths. Possibly one of those paths passes through some material and the other passes through only vacuum or air. But interferometry is a pretty broad field. It would help if you narrow the question down to some specific kind of interferometer, for example.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the difference in the phase shift between the two beams of the interferometer?

Answer (score 0):

Optical phase shift of interferometer is actually defined in terms of wavelength, refractive index and length of arm of interferrometer as propogation light along its optical path depends on these 3 parameters in device.

The laser can use tunable wavelength to detect that optical phase shift.

[image]